# How to list Apache enabled modules?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, http

Is there a command that list all enabled Apache modules?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

To list apache loaded modules use:

```
apachectl -M
```

or:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

or on RHEL,CentoS, Fedora:

```
httpd -M
```

For more options `man apachectl`. All these answers can be found just by little google search.

Comment: `-M` will also work.

Comment: I love this comment about google search (found this answer via google)

Comment: The use of server-info is harder to find via google and gives much more details && the ability to give access to the information to people who don't have shell access (eg client, web developpers, project managers, ...)

Comment: `man apachectl` on Ubuntu 20.04 does not include this option (or others), but the command still works. The man page isn't that helpful here

Comment: Prefix command with sudo e.g. `sudo httpd -M` if you get errors like local ssl cert not found etc. Its due to permission issue.

Comment: You can use `apache2ctl -M` or `a2query -m`

Comment: `All these answers can be found just by little google search.` ... Google got me here :D. (Meta 301 loop..)

Answer (score 11):

Also you can use [server-info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html) to get info from remote servers

```
<Location /server-info>
   SetHandler server-info
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

You can get list of all enabled Apache modules at http://your.host.example.com/server-info?list

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable the info module:

```
sudo a2enmod info.load
sudo a2enmod info.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After restart:

```
http://localhost/server-info
```

will provide a long list of modules, and configuration info.

To view from remote servers, you can change the 'Requires' option in /etc/apache2/mods-available/info.conf to allow remote servers to view info.

Comment: Why not use the ````a2enmod```` command to enable an {installed} module, instead of "symlinking" it manually?

Comment: Yes a2enmod is more correct. When I'm editing configs I usually stay with the files and don't think of the specialty commands that I rarely use.

Comment: Okay, it works both ways anyway, in 2.4 (maybe already earlier also?) you also have the ````a2enconf```` to symlink files from "conf-available" directory to "conf-enabled" :)

Answer (score 8):

On more recent iterations of Debian and Ubuntu there is also the `a2query` command:

```
a2query -m
authz_host (enabled by maintainer script)
ssl (enabled by site administrator)
...
```

Usage:

```
Usage: /usr/sbin/a2query -q -m [MODULE] -s [SITE] -c [CONF] -a -v -M -d -h
-q              suppress any output. Useful for invocation from scripts
-m [MODULE]     checks whether the module MODULE is enabled, lists all enabled
modules if no argument was given
-s [SITE]       checks whether the site SITE is enabled, lists all sites if no
argument was given
-c [CONF]       checks whether the configuration CONF is enabled, lists all
configurations if no argument was given
-a              returns the current Apache 2 module magic version
-v              returns the current Apache 2 version
-M              returns the enabled Apache 2 MPM
-d              returns the Apache 2 module directory
-h              display this help
```

Comment: `a2query -m` is a gem! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works also:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are old and no longer work for my modern Fedora Server 31 / 32 and Apache 2.4.

Here's what does:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

But, there is a caveat that this will only work if you have an appropriately configured /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, so if you're in the middle of editing to set LogLevel, it won't work if your edits are in-progress and not valid!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

```
sudo a2enmod info.load
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After restart:

```
sudo wget http://localhost/server-info --no-check-certificate && cat server-info
```

Answer (score -1):

For security and hardening purposes, here's the list of modules that are found on a Wordpress site by default:
It may be useful to paste these into a text file (with gedit, nano, or vim) and `diff` it against the result of `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`
Remember to use vim VISUAL to highlight your file and `<` to remove any indentation.

Loaded modules:

- core_module (static)
- so_module (static)
- watchdog_module (static)
- http_module (static)
- log_config_module (static)
- logio_module (static)
- version_module (static)
- unixd_module (static)
- access_compat_module (shared)
- alias_module (shared)
- auth_basic_module (shared)
- authn_core_module (shared)
- authn_file_module (shared)
- authz_core_module (shared)
- authz_host_module (shared)
- authz_user_module (shared)
- autoindex_module (shared)
- deflate_module (shared)
- dir_module (shared)
- env_module (shared)
- filter_module (shared)
- mime_module (shared)
- mpm_prefork_module (shared)
- negotiation_module (shared)
- php_module (shared)
- reqtimeout_module (shared)
- rewrite_module (shared)
- setenvif_module (shared)
- status_module (shared)

Comment: This may help you. It could be different for everybody else. It's not WordPress that indicates which modules are enabled.