# 301 redirect through Apache .CONF file

Tags: apache-2.4

I would like to ask you a question. Is it possible to redirect the old URL to a new url (old sub-page to new sub-page) (301 redirect) in Apache through etc/apache/sites-available/...conf file?

I found this code. I am not sure if it works. The problem is that it's not a redirection of sub-pages.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
Redirect 301 /oldlocation http://www.domain2.com/newlocation
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not very good at this so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done the research for your offtopic question [here's a tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) and shortly said yes it is possible

Comment: NEVER EVER CONFIGURE A 301 REDIRECT until you've got the desired configuration working with a 302.

Answer (score 0):

Apache conf files have their own syntax. In my experience, it takes some exposure and experimentation before one starts to understand them. Your example uses the [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive, which appears to be implemented as part of `mod_alias`. Your apache server may or may not have mod_alias enabled. To see what apache modules are enabled, see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/475173/how-to-list-apache-enabled-modules).

The `Redirect` directive doesn't look very flexible. The docs say:

> The Redirect directive maps an old URL into a new one by asking the client to refetch the resource at the new location.

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative path is not allowed.

> The new URL may be either an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname, or a URL-path beginning with a slash. In this latter case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

You might consider checking out [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) which is more advanced & flexible. It implements pattern matching behaviors which will probably give you more powerful ways to send an old url to new one. Your post appears to redirect not just to a new domain but also changes 'oldlocation' to 'newlocation'. You may need to implement some kind of elaborate [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) thing, depending on how you have changed your urls.